# How to save JMeter summary report in non-gui mode execution?

Tags: jmeter

How to save Summary Result report as it was shown in GUI mode?

[image: Screenshot Summary Result]
Configured as below to save the file,
[image: Screenshot Summary Result]
CSV File,
[image: Screenshot Summary Result]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is using [JMeter Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

1. Install JMeter Plugins CMD Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/). Most probably you will need [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) as well
2. When you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you should get a .jtl result file
3. At this moment you will be able to [generate a CSV representation of the Summary Report using JMeter Plugins CMD tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv summary-report.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
4. When the script finishes open `summary-report.csv` using [MS Excel](https://products.office.com/en-ww/excel?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I was looking results to be stored in csv file as it is shown in summary result when we are running through NON-GUI mode.
As now what i have configured is,